# SVG not rendering in IE but works fine on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, svg

I have a react app that uses react-toggle. I'm trying to set the inner HTML in the application. It works fine on IE and it doesn't render anything on IE.

Code snippet:

```
      componentDidMount() {
// Change text hardcoded in plugin
const ontext = document.getElementsByClassName('react-toggle-track-check');
for (let idx = 0; idx < ontext.length; idx++) {
  ontext[idx].innerHTML = '<svg width="50" height="11" viewBox="0 0 50 11"><text x="20" y="9" style="font-size: 10; fill:#FFFFFF">ON</text><text x="38" y="9" style="font-family: FontAwesome;font-size: 12px;  fill:#FFFFFF;"">&#xf023;</text></svg>';
}
const offtext = document.getElementsByClassName('react-toggle-track-x');
for (let idx = 0; idx < offtext.length; idx++) {
  offtext[idx].style.width = '15px';
  offtext[idx].innerHTML = '<svg width="50" height="11" viewBox="0 0 50 11"><text x="0" y="9" style="font-size: 10; fill:#FFFFFF">OFF</text><text x="23" y="9" style="font-family: FontAwesome;font-size: 12px;  fill:#FFFFFF;">&#xf023;</text></svg>';
  }
}
```

[Screenshot on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGcMl.png)

[image: Screenshot on IE]

Comment: try adding `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   version="1.0"` to the svg tag ... an also, you have a typo at the end of one of them `fill:#FFFFFF;""` ... two x " ?

Comment: Can you please explain the typo? I didnt get that part @Jaromanda

Comment: The innerHTML text, with  svg elements works in IE - although you may have to change the &#xf023; character to something available in a default font, add units to `font-size` value and set a background color. But it doesn't look anything like the screen shot. To me this suggests a Font Awesome issue rather than SVG. Try creating a reproducible minimum test case.

Comment: re the typo: `style="font-family: FontAwesome;font-size: 12px;  fill:#FFFFFF;""` isn't it obvious? the `""` at the end should be `"`

Comment: What does this mean??? " It works fine on IE and it doesn't render anything on IE."

Comment: Michael, the text inside the toggle component with the fa icon doesn't render

Comment: You can't create SVG with innerHTML in IE. You'll need to use individual createElementNS calls.